# Smtplib doesn't Work

Tags: python, smtplib

I got the script from the first example here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#email-examples

I made sure there is  no file name similar to email.py.

```html
import smtplib
# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

fp = open(textfile, 'rb')
# Create a text/plain message
msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
fp.close()

# me == the sender's email address
# you == the recipient's email address
msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of %s' % textfile
msg['From'] = torontocoinowl@gmail.com
msg['To'] = torontocoinowl@gmail.com

# Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the
# envelope header.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

The error is

```html
C:\Users\donald\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe C:/Users/donald/PycharmProjects/untitled3/testingemail/ff.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/donald/PycharmProjects/untitled3/testingemail/ff.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\Users\donald\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "C:\Users\donald\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\email\utils.py", line 28, in <module>
    import random
  File "C:\Users\donald\PycharmProjects\untitled3\random.py", line 1
    From random import randint
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having a file `random.py` in your folder. It clashes with the random modul in Python. Remove of rename that file!